# how to change content without reloading the page?

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

Ok, so lets say that I have navbar eg.

`<ul>
<li class="selected">home</li>
<li>about me</li>
<li>contact</li>
<ul>`

and I have a content on a page that I want to change depending on which `<li>` is selected without reloading the whole page. It seems a bit pointless to reload the whole page just to update 2 divs.

eg. when home is selected I want to load home.php included in `<div class='content'>` + change class of `<li> home</li>` to selected etc.

should I use AJAX for this? or should I use $_GET -> altering the URL?

I am a beginner -> sorry for basic questions.

Thx for any kind of help!

Comment: Ajax(Asynchronous Javascript and XML) is the key!!!

Comment: @satishsharma where do you see a duplicate? Question is AJAX or $_GET and not an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Ajax.

But if you're total beginner, **another solution without Ajax** :

• put all your content in a single file

• put IDs on your div, related to the content (div containing "about" content = div#about)

• just toggle the div on click, related to the content

Like this (JS with jQuery) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('nav a').click(function(){
    var dest = $(this).attr('href');
    $('div.content').fadeOut(); // Hide all content divs
    $(dest).fadeIn(); // Show the requested part
    // You can do all of this using addClass / removeClass and use CSS transition (smoother, cleaner);
  return false;  
});
});
```

HTML updated:

```
<ul> <li class="selected"><a href="#home">home</a></li> <li><a href="#about">about me</a></li> <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li> <ul>
```

**If you had no idea of what is Ajax, I guess this solution is better for you.**

Answer (score 0):

To change part of your page from a new request, use Ajax.  You can find a lot about it online.

That said, using ajax for basic navigation of a simple website is bad taste.  Just do a normal navigation.