# Switch between sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to switch from main (home) section to, for instance, about section. I want to just replace my main content with new about section (whole bootstrap container). I want to make it fade out while about section comes in. Of course, without refreshing the page. Like on this website (try switching sections): https://covid19stats.live/

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you really want..

but normally you place your content in different .html files and refer to them with a button or a link:

```
<a href="about.html" 
   title="more informations">
    Href-attribute
</a>
```

edit: if you want to just change the content you need to use Ajax

look here [how to change content without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698459/how-to-change-content-without-reloading-the-page)